# UNDERFLOW keyword with gcc on MSYS2

Tags: c, gcc, msys2, gcc11, gcc12

I ran into some really weird problem with the compilation of a very simple code

```
typedef volatile struct _underflow_test
{
    unsigned int    OPERATION_MODE;
    unsigned int    UNDERFLOW;
} underflow_test;
```

This code fails to compile in MSYS2 using `gcc12.2`. Using the `-E` option I have checked that the code about is converted to this:

```
typedef volatile struct _underflow_test
{
    unsigned int OPERATION_MODE;
    unsigned int 
# 4137 "C:/Users/work/eec_control/TC367_project/Libraries/Infra/Sfr/TC36A/_Reg/IfxGeth_regdef.h" 3
                      4
# 4137 "C:/Users/work/eec_control/TC367_project/Libraries/Infra/Sfr/TC36A/_Reg/IfxGeth_regdef.h"
                               ;
} underflow_test;
```

So preprocessor converted `UNDERFLOW` into just 4. Then this conversion fails to compile.
Using the `gcc11` doesn't do this - it doesn't convert `UNDERFLOW` field into 4.

The command line is the same in both cases:

```
cd C:/Users/work/build-eec-gnu/core_files/bsp && C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe 
-DROOT_INSTALL_DIR="\"C:/Program Files (x86)/eec-control\"" 
@CMakeFiles/bsp-core-tc367-a1.dir/includes_C.rsp 
-Wall -Wextra -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfloat-equal -Wconversion -Wparentheses -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wstrict-prototypes  
-DMAJOR_RELEASE_NUMBER=1 -DMINOR_RELEASE_NUMBER=0 -DPATCH_RELEASE_NUMBER=42 -E -O0 -DNDEBUG -g 
-fdiagnostics-color=always -std=gnu99 -MD -MT core_files/bsp/CMakeFiles/bsp-core-tc367-a1.dir/hal.c.obj 
-MF CMakeFiles/bsp-core-tc367-a1.dir/hal.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/bsp-core-tc367-a1.dir/hal.c.obj 
-c C:/Users/work/eec_control/core_files/bsp/hal.c
```

Anyone know what could be causing this and how to solve this strange effect? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, you have `#define UNDERFLOW 4` in `C:/Users/work/eec_control/TC367_project/Libraries/Infra/Sfr/TC36A/_Reg/IfxGeth_regdef.h`.

Comment: If I did, the same error would have occurred with `gcc11`. But it doesn't.

Comment: The command line you are showing compiles `hal.c` as C, not C++. So why is `c++` tagged? Your test code doesn't include anything, so where is the mentioned file included from? Also `_underflow_test` is a reserved name in the global namespace scope in C++ and may not be defined by the user because it starts with an underscore.

Comment: Well, you need to debug it. Maybe the macro is defined conditionally, and is disabled in GCC 11. Maybe GCC 11 doesn't use that header at all. Figure out why.

Comment: `UNDERFLOW` seems to be defined by `#include <math.h>` if neither `__STRICT_ANSI__` nor `NO_OLDNAMES` is defined. See https://github.com/mirror/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/crt/math.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to [Ian Abbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264491/ian-abbott) for the nudge to the right direction. It was caused by the `#define` collision between the common code and my supplier's code. The supplier's code expected strict ANSI code without GNU extensions.

The fix is to set the CMake extensions flag using `set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)`.